# better way to proceed instead of repeating

Tags: javascript

I assume there is a better way then repeating the same process over and over for each one?

and the collision method, the collision method only works with center to center collision, which is really good.

```
var ereset = function(){
    //Attacker 1
    att1.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    att1.y = -60 ;  
    //Attacker 2
    att2.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    att2.y = -60 ;      
    //Attacker 3
    att3.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    att3.y = -60 ;  
    //Attacker 4
    att4.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    att4.y = -60 ;  
    //Attacker 5
    att5.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    att5.y = -60 ;  
}



  if (
        hero.x <= (att1.x + 20 || att1.x + 32)
        && att1.x <= (hero.x + 20 || att1.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (att1.y + 20 || att1.y - 32)
        && att1.y <= (hero.y + 20 || att1.y - 32)
    ){
        end();
    } else if(
        hero.x <= (att2.x + 20 || att2.x + 32)
        && att2.x <= (hero.x + 20 || att2.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (att2.y + 20 || att2.y - 32)
        && att2.y <= (hero.y + 20 || att2.y - 32)
    ){
        end();
    }else if(
        hero.x <= (att3.x + 20 || att3.x + 32)
        && att3.x <= (hero.x + 20 || att3.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (att3.y + 20 || att3.y - 32)
        && att3.y <= (hero.y + 20 || att3.y - 32)
    ){
        end();
    }else if(
        hero.x <= (att4.x + 20 || att4.x + 32)
        && att4.x <= (hero.x + 20 || att4.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (att4.y + 20 || att4.y - 32)
        && att4.y <= (hero.y + 20 || att4.y - 32)
    ){
        end();
    }

};
```

Comment: make a function? Pass in the object with the values.

Comment: An array and a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing the same thing to each attacker, it's probably best to make a function that does that action, and run it against each attacker. Here, I'll put all the attackers in an array and use `forEach` to iterate through the list.

```
var attackers = [
    att1, att2, att3, att4, att5
];

function ereset(){
    attackers.forEach(moveAttacker);
}

function moveAttacker(attacker){
    attacker.x = 0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    attacker.y = -60 ; 
}
```

Comment: This solution would be even better if `ereset` accepted `attackers` as an argument. The less free variables - the better.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that... Thanks :)

Comment: @zerkms I decided against that because `ereset()` looks like a control method like `play()` or `stop()` that may be called from places that don't necessarily have access to the list of attackers. If resetting the attackers what more complex than just moving them, I would think about making another function called `resetAttackers()` that would take the array as an argument.

Comment: @Patrick Gunderson: that's actually a **good** point. I wish I could upvote twice just for that.

Answer (score 0):

OOP Job:

```
var Attacker = function() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    this.init = function(ix, iy) {
      this.x = ix;
      this.y = iy;
    };
};

var ereset = function(){

    this.attackers = 5;
    this.swat = [];

    for ( var n = 0; n < this.attackers; n++ )
    {
         var att = new Attacker();
         att.init(0 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64)), -60 );
         this.swat.push(att);
    }
};

var checkHero = function (hero, attackers)
{
      for ( var n = 0; n < attackers.length; n++  )
      {
         if (
             hero.x <= (attackers[n].x + 20 || attackers[n].x + 32)
             && attackers[n].x <= (hero.x + 20 || attackers[n].x + 32)
             && hero.y <= (att1.y + 20 || attackers[n].y - 32)
             && attackers[n].y <= (hero.y + 20 || attackers[n].y - 32)
            ){
               end();
         }
       }
 };
```

or something like this, this is not tested code, just an approach!

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating how OO is usually bloated compared to procedural/functional :-) PS: it would be better to use constructor instead of `init`

Comment: "bloated" - this is totally generic and easily extensible code. Why else should we all have OOP then? You may go with fortran77, that's pure functional, and be happy.

Comment: constructor - due to the name "ereset" I assumed that this is merely a function to __reset__ things than create them. Semantics ...

Comment: "Why else should we all have OOP then? You may go with fortran77, that's pure functional, and be happy." --- I actually try to use pure functional languages and I am happy :-) So, existence of something is a bad justification for using something. Not to mention that this code does not bring any benefits over object literals apart of that "bloatness"

Comment: @zerkms I must admit that from a certain point on you need to get functional when it comes to the real stuff ...

Comment: constructor for `Attacker`.